# Can PlannerTasks be expanded to include their related Details property?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I've written a query which I thought would return the [`PlannerTasks`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/plannertask) in a [`PlannerPlan`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/plannerplan), with their [`details`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/plannertask#relationships) property populated.

```
var tasks = await graphServiceClient
    .Planner
    .Plans[this.planId]
    .Tasks
    .Request()
    .Expand("details")
    .GetAsync();
```

But it gave an error:

> Specified expansions, filters, or select statements are not supported for this query.

This appears to mean that `Expand` on `Details` isn't supported, but it's not specific about that, and it doesn't say why.

Is it not supported at all?

Is it because I'm doing it in a way that isn't supported, but there's another way that is?

I had a look at the documentation for [`Expand`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#expand-parameter) and it said:

> Note: Not all relationships and resources support the $expand query
>   parameter. For example, you can expand the directReports, manager, and
>   memberOf relationships on a user, but you cannot expand its events,
>   messages, or photo relationships. Not all resources or relationships
>   support using $select on expanded items.

But [the documentation doesn't appear to detail which relationships are or aren't expandable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885386/is-there-a-list-of-relationships-that-do-do-not-support-expansion-in-the-microso).

So I can't tell if I'm taking the wrong approach, that it's not supported and I should move on, or if it's a bug.

One final question, if expand isn't supported for `Details`, does that mean I have to make a call for each task individually?

Comment: I saw that you've posted a few questions about using task details in ways that aren't currently supported. If you can describe your scenario or what you are trying to accomplish, I maybe able to suggest an approach.

Comment: We're integrating Planner Tasks in to an existing webapp for a client, with a custom UI, and trying to not too badly abuse the Planner workflow along the way. The Tasks only have a paragraph or two of text in their description fields, and the client would like the description text to be visible in the Task list of the custom UI. We're using buckets to indicate "Task Type", and labels for things like "urgency".

Comment: We considered using the Title field to hold the text, but that's already being used to hold the Project ID (a human friendly string the client uses to identify each project). We initially looked at creating a new Plan per Project, but creating Plans isn't supported with an Application level token, and we don't want every user to have permission to create plans. This approach hopefully means they can still use the Planner webapp if needed, but have a slightly enhanced experience inside their own webapp.

Comment: We'll probably run some tests to find out the speed of individually requesting the description for a fairly large number of tasks. And if that time is reasonable, ask the client if they would prefer faster loading of the task list without descriptions, or slower loading with.

Comment: I see, the data/scenario seems to be a bit misaligned with the schema we have. With the requirement of showing paragraphs of text per task, description is the only option, other text fields won't support that data size. You can probably use batch requests to improve the performance, as described here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching

Comment: Thanks for the advice, we've taken the options back to the client and they were okay with not showing the descriptions in the Task list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now expand details while reading tasks in a plan.

Outdated Reply:

> Expansion of task details is not supported when querying any lists of
> tasks (e.g. tasks in a plan). Task details object can contain large
> blocks of data, it is not meant to be queried across tasks.